# Parser exception in an Android manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am making a action bar. But when I try to run my program, I get a log message telling me that there is a problem with the manifest file.

> `[2012-07-17 09:18:07 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for E:\Android\workspace\actionbar\AndroidManifest.xml: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.`

What is the meaning of this message? How can I fix my manifest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="actio.bar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
      <activity android:name=".TabNavigationActionBarActivity" android:label="Action Bar Demonstration: TabNav">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name=".DropdownListNavigationActionBarActivity" android:label="Action Bar Demonstration: DropdownNav" /> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

you did not close the opening application tag.

```
<application
```

should be

```
<application>
```

Answer (score 1):

That error can be cause by many reasons. One could be that you have a space at the very begining of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

So, at the very beginning of the first line, look for and delete any leading spaces.

Hope that helps.